# Selenium hanging and timing out on basic page interactions on OWA.

Tags: ruby, email, selenium, timeout, webdriver

I'm using Selenium with a local FireFox browser to access live.com's spam box and read the email. For testing purposes, I've been using "binding.pry" to interact with my script and see where the problems are.

When I try to find the element representing an inbox message:

```
driver.find_element(:css,"#messageListContentContainer .ia_hc")
```

I get this error after 60 seconds:

```
Timeout::Error: execution expired
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:in `rbuf_fill'
```

But, as I'm in Pry, I can quickly repeat the same command. After about 5 or 10 seconds, it finds the element.

Obviously I can get around the problem by putting a `before`, `rescue`, `retry` block around the call, but that means I'll have to wait 70-80 seconds to click a single email. Does anyone have any idea why find_element is taking so long that it times out, or why it doesn't time out the second time? Is it because the live.com (called "Outlook Mail" on the website) has a huge ammount of elements to search through? Is it something with the JavaScript they are using?

I've been able to duplicate this issue with both Firefox and PhantomJS

UPDATE:: I've found this is happening with all of the calls after any page refresh. I can call driver.page_source and I have the same problem. It seems selenium can't interact with the browser for a certain period of time after the page has refreshed. Could it be that selenium is having trouble reading everything off of the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen in my own tests, but on an intermittent basis, and never completely reproducible. What seems to happen is that Selenium WebDriver just becomes blocked and unresponsive.

I know that I have just had to resort to rescuing the error, logging, and retrying in my code. After a few retrys, Selenium WebDriver seems to become responsive again and I'm able to continue on in my tests from there.

I have contacted the maintainer of the Ruby WebDriver gem, and he needs a reproducible test to be able to do some solid debugging. If you are able to provide a reproducible test case, please share it with us so that we can look into this issue. You can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bbbco/6001743) as a starting point to share with the community.

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only one with the problem. Where do I submit my code? It's definitely reproducible. This happens every time.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a Gist with the reproducible case (you can use my template from the gist above to get started) and then sharing the link on here, as well as submitting a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list and including the reproducible case there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem just magically disappeared. It's not happening anymore and I can't duplicate it. Best of luck to the selenium crew finding it, it seems to come and go randomly.

Comment: Bummer. Jari B (maintainer) tweeted back to me that he saw no actionable info ... suggested possible local network issues?